# Implementing a Language Server for Antlr4-based custom-made language

Tags: antlr4, xtext, eclipse-che

I have a simple Antlr4-based project that I have created by following the README provided in [this repo](https://github.com/antlr4ide/antlr4ide). I want to implement the grammar rules that I've built into a language server that I can integrate with the Eclipse Che IDE.

[Here is the Antlr4 project](https://github.com/SharkJ/MyAntlrTest) that I've created.

With the help of Xtext and Antlr4 communities I've learnt that ANTLR4 does not come with a language server as Xtext does. Though I have succefully implemented language servers using Xtext, I am very new to Antlr4 and I'm quite confused in this matter. So what is the basic procedure used to implement an Antlr4 DSL to a language server? Is it possible or not?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: stackoverflow is really meant for questions that can be answered. Your question really boils down to "can someone guide me to do X", to which the answer could be either "yes" or "no". I recommend you try to solve your problem yourself, and when you get stuck, ask a more specific question here. If you have no idea where to start, then you'd better not be doing it and practice with something easier. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I updated my question.